# Dimensional analysis and more: Order of divergences in the $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, regularization, self-energy

On page 324 of his book on qft, Peskin analyzes the superficial degree of divergence of the 1-loop self-energy correction of the $\phi^4$ scalar theory. Realizing that $D=2$, he concludes that the diagram's divergent part has the form

$$
\sim \Lambda^2 + p^2\log \Lambda^2.
$$

**(1)** Why is there no linear term? Is there a symmetry reason like the chiral one in the Yukawa theory? How general is it? Also, why does every logarithm, in the cases that dimensional analysis predicts a dimensionless divergence, contains $\Lambda^2$ instead of any other power of it?

Furthermore, he calculates the counterterms to be

$$
\delta_m = \frac{4g^2}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\int_0^1 dx \; \frac{\Gamma(1-\frac{d}{2})}{[m_f^2 - x(1-x)m^2]^{1-d/2}},
$$

and

$$
\delta_Z=-\frac{g^2}{4\pi^2} \int_0^1 dx \; x(1-x)\left (\frac{2}{\epsilon} - \gamma + \log 4\pi -\log[m_f^2 - x(1-x)m^2] \right).
$$

**(2)** He states that the first is a quadratically divergent mass renormalization -- how can I realize that? I imagine it is a property of the $\Gamma$ function, but it is not clear.

He also says that the field strength renormalization is  logarithmic one -- how can I compare the $1/\epsilon$ of the dimensional regularization to the momentum cutoff analysis that results from the superficial degree of divergence, to realize this is a logarithmic one?

**(3)** Later, talking about the Renormalization Group, on page 409, he remembers that the self energy correction on Yukawa theory

$$
\frac{\Gamma(1-\frac{d}{2})}{\Delta^{1-d/2}},
$$

and deals with the fact that this has a pole on $d=2$ which is ultimately canceled. But, in any case, why is this important? I thought that only the $d \to 4$ limit was important. Why does this analysis must be carried? I imagine it has to do with the possibility for the analytic continuation, but have no idea how.

If it looks like too many questions, tackling what may seem to you to be the source of my misunderstanding would already be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a small comment on one subpart of your question. The power of $\Lambda$ in the log is just a convention. If we parameterize $\Lambda$ raised to a general power as $\Lambda^{2k}$ for some real $k$, then $\log \Lambda^{2k} =\log [(\Lambda^2)^k] = k \log \Lambda^2$.

Comment: @Andrew Ohhh, and then the arbitrary factor gets absorbed within the calculated constant! Thank you!